# How to start IONIC application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, visual-studio-code, ionic3

I'm installing Ionic with the aim of learning this Framework, but I'm not getting results when I give the command `ionic serve` .... I get the following error: `[ERROR] Sorry! ionic serve can only be run in an Ionic project directory.`

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlK9J.png)

While I create my project files, I do not know if these are well named .... I attach a photo of these

[explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3820.png)

I have installed Node, Apache Cordova and Ionic ... I do not know what's happening ... any help for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that inside `primerapp` folder